# How can I do a mass file rename in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there an edit cut program with a search highlight option?  For instance say I want to save several files from the temporary internet files and I don't want the (1), tail, on the file name.  I could remove the (1), tail, on the file name manually but  If the number of files is over 50, the process is a bit time consumming as well as tedious.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too tired, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the question... Can you perhaps dumb down the example slightly?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to mass-rename a bunch of files, is that right?

Comment: Thanx for commenting...I'm tired too so I'll be back tomarrow after some much needed rest..and I'll try to explain my question with a little less? detail.

Comment: Yes Flimzy.  That sounds about it,  But I don't want a large resource hog.

Comment: i asked a similar question a year and a half ago; never got an answer.  http://superuser.com/questions/149537/windows-file-copy-move-with-filename-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

I like [Bulk File Rename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Answer (score 1):

I like CyLog’s [WildRename](http://www.cylog.org/utilities/wildrename.jsp). It supports wildcards and regular expressions for file selection and string substitutions. It also includes logging, case-conversion, a counter ability (eg rename files to `blah1.txt`, `blah2.txt`, `blah3.txt`, etc.), and even rename simulation (see the results without making any actual changes).

One of the main uses I had for it was specifically to remove the `[1]` from files that I downloaded with IE (or the `(1)` from files saved in Chromium). This is simple with WildRen, just create regex string-substitution rule (which you can enable or disable as needed, so you can keep it permanently):

```
Replace:
  \(\d{1,2}\)\.
With:
  .
```

It will delete all occurrences of parentheses surrounding one or two numeric digits. (And you can go from there.)

Answer (score 0):

Try [regexrenamer](http://regexrenamer.sourceforge.net/):

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) should give you a good start. Otherwise a web search for 'regular expressions tutorial' or something like that should help.

Comment: thanx Cam.  I'll take a look at it.